# One Drive is always Processing too many changes

Tags: windows-10, office365, onedrive

I am using Windows10 x64 and OneDrive (I think it is for business).  No matter if I only open 1 file from the OneDrive folder the little icon will say it is processing 187 changes.  It takes a lot longer to finish syncing to the cloud as it does these extra 186 changes, whatever they might be.

Is this a bug or a setting I need to change?  I've tried re-installing (from Office 365) but no luck.

I only get this problem on my HP laptop.  My Dell PC (Win10 x64, same Office 365 installation) has the number of changes to process that I would expect given the number of files I've been editing/creating.

Any ideas?